# Calling controller action method directly from Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I looked around and couldn't find an easy solution.

I've tried `@GetUserName` which doesn't work.
I've tried `@ { GetUserName` which doesn't work.

There has to be an easy way to call a method from the razor view engine.

It is within a `foreach` loop.

I need `GetUserName(item.userID)`

The below code is in my controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public string GetUserName(int userID)
{
     ProPit_User user = db.ProPit_User.Find(userID);

     return user.username;
}
```

Comment: have you tried initilizing the object to call the method

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, I would reconsider that design. If you still have to follow that approach, you can call child actions from the views using `@Html.Action("GetUserName", "YourController", new { userID = 1 })`

Comment: Check This: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Multiple-ways-to-call-Controller-Action-Method-from-a-Razor-View

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Trying to call a controller action method directly from your view is usually a sign of bad design.

You have a few options, depending on what you are trying to do:

1. Avoid calling the method, instead put the data in your model, and render the model
2. Use [Html.RenderAction](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/)
3. Put the method in another class and use normal function syntax.

(1) is usually my default approach, often incorporating [DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplates](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html)

For (3), e.g.

```
public static class Util
{
    public string MyUtilMethod(int blah)
}
```

And the view:

```
@Util.MyUtilMethod(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Although you *can* obtain the controller instance from your view, doing so is plain wrong as it violates the whole MVC (and MVVM) paradigm, as the view should not be aware of its controller.

(The only possible reason I can think of where this would be useful would perhaps be for testing the controller from a mocked view, although even here, it should be possible to test the exposed controller functionality directly from unit tests):

```
@{
    var controller = ViewContext.Controller as MyController;
    var userName = controller.GetUserName(123);
}
```

The better way to have arrived at this result is for the controller to pre-populate, and [pass](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) all the data needed by the `View`, such as the `userName`, to a custom `ViewModel` (as typed by the `@model` directive at the top of the Razor page), or to the `ViewBag` dynamic.

Comment: I'd -1 this, but I'd feel dirty just getting my mouse near this answer.

Comment: Well, yes, it answers the OP's question viz `There has to be an easy way to call a method from the razor view engine.`, but as everyone is saying, this would generally be an insane thing to do.

Comment: Everyone should be happy I wrote a seperate model and it now works as I desired with passing everything through the model. :)

Comment: @DanielGimenez instead of that you could have pointed out what's wrong and corrected it. It's not like many come to SO already knowing the answers...