# Is There Any Way To Call Method Within Foreach Loop In Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach

I want to get data and show data within for each loop. Please provide sample code Complete newbie in MVC.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cntryName)
                //---- Here I want to call another method based on contryId and bind details
                in another table

            </td>
```

Comment: You and use ajax and call your controller and then parse result to your view. Some example: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/218ca630-ba50-48fe-af6e-6f754b5894aa.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843324/calling-controller-action-method-directly-rom-razor-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an HtmlHelper extension

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
      public static string YourTableEmittingMethod(this HtmlHelper helper, int countryId)
      {
        //Add your logic to create html string using the countryId 
        //and return string containing the Html tags for the table
      }
   }
}
```

then you can use this method in the your mvc view as   `@Html.YourTableEmittingCode(@item.CountryId)`

Read more about HtmlExtensions [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Answer (score 0):

Why not return all required data in the model?

From the model sent to the view, perform your loop such that the model returned to the view has all the data needed. It is much neater to write your logic codes in your cs file than on your view.