# Call Method in Controller from View(cshtml)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi im trying to call a method from controller from view just to display the "staff_name"

**Controller**

```
 public JsonResult getStaffName(int staff_id)
    {
        var staffname = (from a in db.master_staff where b.staff_id == staff_id 
            select a.staff_name).SingleOrDefault();

        return Json(staffname,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View**

```
int[] staff_id = { 24,25,26 }; 

@foreach (var n in staff_id){ 

//call method getStaffName from Controller to get "staff_name" 

}
```

it suppose to get the "staff_name" according to the "staff_id"

is there any possible method for this situation?

Comment: You need to call the ajax request. Start looking into that.

Comment: You can put this var staffname = (from a in db.master_staff where b.staff_id == staff_id 
            select a.staff_name).SingleOrDefault(); in your foreach directly

Comment: You need to write javascript code. Otherwise you can use razor. Create a function that does not return JsonResult and inject it inside the view. This should happen through ServiceLocation pattern. You will also need a DI container.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843324/calling-controller-action-method-directly-from-razor-view

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```cs
@Html.Action("getStaffName", "YourController", staff_id)
```

For more info, look at child actions: https://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/

However, I do not know what you are trying to achieve with this.

Answer (score 1):

To call method from controller to view you have to use ajax call from view.
here is ajax call syntax in asp.net mvc:

```
 $.ajax({ 
          type: "GET", 
          url: '@Url.Action("controller method name", "controller name")', 
          data: { searchText: value }, 
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
          dataType: 'json', 
          success: function (result) { 
           },
           error: { 
           } 
        });
```

1. type can be `GET` or `POST` depending on your controller method type.
2. In URL attribute two parameters are passed the first one is controller method name and second one is controller name.
3. In data attribute you have to pass the values which are required to pass in controller from view such as parameters in controller method.
4. In success and error attribute you have to write a block of code which should be executed in both cases. such as display data on UI upon success and error message on failure.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do this. It is the way to the Dark side :) And each JSON request is taking some time.

1. Create model to store your staff
2. Fill it in controller (or even better in some business logic class)
3. Display in your view

   ```
   public ActionResult Staff()
   {
       // This would be nice to have as separate Data Access Layery class
       var staffs = GetStaffs();
       return View(staffs);
   }

   private static StaffDto[] GetStaffs()
   {
       // One call to database is better that several
       var staffs = db.master_staff
           .Where(x => x.staff_id > 0) // Any other condition, if needed
           .Select(x => new StaffDto(x.staff_id, x.staff_name))
           .ToArray();
       return staffs;
   }

   // Data Transfer Object class to separate database from presentation view
   public class StaffDto
   {
       public int StaffId { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public StaffDto(int staffId, string name)
       {
           StaffId = staffId;
           Name = name;
       }
   }
   ```

Your view file (Staff.cshtml in my case)

```
@model IEnumerable<TestMvc.Controllers.StaffDto>
<div>
@foreach (var staff in Model)
{
    @staff.Name<br />
}
</div>
```

And, as bonus, you could unit test it easily

```
private readonly HomeController _homeController = new HomeController();

[TestMethod]
public void Staff_CheckCount()
{
    var result = _homeController.Staff();

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
    var actual = ((ViewResult)result).Model as StaffDto[];
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, actual.Length);
}
```

Comment: I disagree with your answer the author might not be able to pass it from the view.
I think a better way is injecting through a service inside the view. Another option is of course the Ajax call. Of course your way works, BUT you are assuming the controller that returns the view is not using the "View" parameter..

Comment: For sure, you could agree or disagree :) But the idea, that staff IDs are existing in view, so it is possible to load data and pass to view. I would agree in case ID is dynamic, but it is not.