# call method from _layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

_layout.cshtml:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Press</a>
```

index.cshtml.cs:

```
public void CallFromA()
{
    //do somting
}
```

**What is the syntax to access the function?**

Comment: What is the purpose of that method? Should it help constructing the HTML for the View or is it an action that produces some (HTTP) response?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If it solves your problem, please mark my answer so it can help others who meet the similar problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To call a method in the controller from a view you will need to use Ajax call from the view.

Have a look at this S.O thread which covers the same topic:

[Call Method in Controller from View(cshtml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59136127/call-method-in-controller-from-viewcshtml)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I think you may wonder how to add method from _layout and call it back on pages. Usually, we don’t add too much method to _layout.cshtml but we still can do it. For example, if you create a new mvc app and choose individual accounts as authentication type, you may find there’s some difference in the _layout.cshtml:

> `<partial name="_LoginPartial" />`

Using this partial view you can finish your goal: Adding methods in Layout pages. However, you can done it without adding partial view. For example, use javascript which enables adding methods to the generated class:

> 

```
@functions{
    public string GetHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

<button Onclick="RazorFunction()">Click</button>

@section Scripts
{
 <script>
    function RazorFunction() {
        $("button").html('@GetHello()');
    }

 </script>
}
```

Here's what I test through this way:

Before I click the button:
[image: Before I click the button]

After I click the button:
[image: After I click the button]